# CSS border-image basic stuff

Tags: html, css, border

It's really simple stuff, but I can't understand what the problem is.

In an ASP.Net webpage I want to create a div with a specific border.

CSS:

```
.ResourcesDiv
{
border-image:url(http://blogrope.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/003-wood-melamine-subttle-pattern-background-pat.jpg) 30 30 stretch;
border: 15px solid transperant;
width: 300px;
padding: 10px 20px;
margin: 50px;
}
```

HTML/ASP:

```
<div id="Resources" class="ResourcesDiv">
In the future, this will display the amount of herbs the user has.<br />
In the future, this will display the amount of gems the user has.<br />
</div>
```

EDIT: It displays a black border if i remove the `transperant` part of the border, but not the image, although I`m pretty sure the url is well set.

Comment: see here http://jsfiddle.net/75hkcaj4/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/e6fpd6er/)

I have changed your CSS as follows

**CSS**

```
.ResourcesDiv {
    border-image:url("http://blogrope.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/003-wood-melamine-subttle-pattern-background-pat.jpg") 30 30 stretch;
    border: 15px solid url("http://blogrope.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/003-wood-melamine-subttle-pattern-background-pat.jpg") 30 30 stretch;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 50px;
}
```

Try it..

**UPDATE**

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/e6fpd6er/2/)--tested in chrome and firefox

Comment: It didn't work... I`m using Firefox. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you have got a spelling mistake in the line

```
border: 15px solid transperant;
```

in the word transparent.

and secondly I think what you want is here at this fiddle: (specific border ,getting from the url you mentioned)

### DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/kq950cvv/

Comment: Although I see it works in the fiddle, it doesn't work for me... Any idea?